# Show that $X_{\textrm{null space}} + X_{\textrm{particular}}$ is a solution of $AX = b$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X_{\textrm{null space}}$ is a vector in $N(A)$ and $X_{\textrm{particular}}$ is a particular solution of $AX = b$, then show that $X_{\textrm{null space}} + X_{\textrm{particular}}$ is also a solution of $AX = b$.

I don't even know where to begin to show that this is true. If anyone can help me, that would be great!

Comment: What have you tried? This seems pretty straightforward from the definitions. Hint: Which equation does$ X_{nullspace}$ satisfy?Also remember that $A(X+Y) = AX + AY$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By definition, we know that:
$$
A(X_{\textsf{nullspace}}) = 0
$$
and:
$$
A(X_{\textsf{particular}}) = b
$$
But then by the linearity of matrix multiplication, we immediately get that...?

Comment: Is this correct? A($X_{particular}$ + $X_{nullspace}$) = A$X_{particular}$ + A$X_{nullspace}$ = b + 0 = b

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: Thank you for your help!